# Sort a list of strings by length, then reverse alphabetically, and then by the second letter (3 criteria) Python

Tags: python-3.x

So I need to sort a list of names by 3 criteria: length first (longest to shortest), then alphabetically (in reverse), then finally alphabetically by the second letter normally.

I've read a lot of questions/answers already but none have helped me solve the issue of the 3rd key.

Example:

```
['Jac', 'Lily', 'Lucy']
```

becomes

```
['Lily', 'Lucy', 'Jac']
```

What I have so far is:

```
lst = ['Jac', 'Lily', 'Lucy']
    
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (len(x), x), reverse = True)
```

This gives me

```
['Lucy', 'Lily', 'Jac']
```

I also tried:

```
sorted(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (len(x), x), reverse = True), key=lambda l: l[1])
```

But this gives me

```
['Jac', 'Lily', 'Lucy']
```

What can I add to now sort the first two names by their second letter?

Comment: `sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (len(x), x[::-1], x[1]))`? It's not clear to me exactly how you want to sort by length, maybe pick an example that doesn't have all equal lengths? But something like that should do it... if it is reverse by *length and alphabetically*, then `sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (len(x), x, -ord(x[1]), reverse=True)` might be "simpler"

Comment: Ah you are probably right about this being a bad example, it's just the test that failed because of the last parameter.

I will give that a try and probably edit the original example.

Comment: Unfortunately @juanpa.arrivillaga your solution still gives the same result. ['Jac', 'Lily', 'Lucy'] becomes ['Lucy', 'Lily', 'Jac'] instead of ['Lily', 'Lucy', 'Jac']

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is sort of strange, you want to keep reverse alphabetical ordering *without* sorting again. So, you want "reverse-alphabetical" **except** for the second item. So, I am afraid something like this monstrosity will have to do:

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (len(x), (x[:1], -ord(x[1]), x[1:])), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (-len(x), -ord(x[0]), ord(x[1])) )
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked to get me the result I needed for that test.